# Is there a PDO equivalent to the mysqli syntax $stmt->bind_param()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**EDITED CODE**
I have a mysqli line of code: `$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['skills'], $_POST['city']);` in a working query.
I've found the need to change to PDO and have used:
`$stmt->bindValue(':skill', $skills, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);`
I get no results except the echoed "No result found. Did you enter a city?" nor error messages although there is a connection to the db as evidenced in the search form in which the select list of 'city' is loaded. The full query:

```
  try {
     global $pdo;
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
     $skills = htmlspecialchars($_POST['skills']);
     $city = htmlspecialchars($_POST['city']);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT skill.skill_name, team.city FROM skill JOIN team ON skill.skill_id=team.skill WHERE skill.skill_name LIKE :skills AND team.city LIKE :city');
     $skills = "%".$skills."%";
     $city = "%".$city."%";
$stmt->bindParam(':skills', $skills, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo $row['skill'] . " is available in " . $row['city'];
    }
}
else {
echo "No result found. Did you enter a city?";
    }
    }
    }//try
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: When in doubt R.T.?.M [PHP PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) The equivalent is strangely enough `->bindParam` ___Cryptic what___

Comment: `->bindValue()` is for getting columns OUT of a result set after a query has been run

Comment: @RiggsFolly When I use  `->bindParam` I get "Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www..."

It seems using a "name" such as "skill.skill_name" for a joined column doesn't work too well. Most of what I've done is from the manual and from other questions/answers here.

Comment: Do you really need to use LIKE or should it be `=`

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's a search form. Is LIKE the same as =? Further checks with my good friend Google gives me the seeming solution but it doesn't work for me either. And I can't detect a typo: `$keyword = "%".$keyword."%";
// Bind the parameter
$sth->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: Your error means you either misspelled `:skill` or `:city` at one of the two places they occur.

Comment: Looks like you solved it yourself. seems to match the answer I had ready if you had answered my question.

Comment: No. `LIKE` is not the same as `=`. Not at all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use `LIKE` then you need a wildcard somewhere in the string. As a placeholder has to represent a complete data literal, and if you want to use `LIKE` you have to create the parameter with the wildcards included like this.

```
try {
    global $pdo;
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $skills = '%' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['skills']) . '%';
        $city = '%' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['city']) . '%';

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT skill.skill_name, team.city 
                               FROM skill 
                                 JOIN team ON skill.skill_id=team.skill 
                               WHERE skill.skill_name LIKE :skill 
                                 AND team.city LIKE :city');

        $stmt->bindValue(':skill', $skills, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                echo $row['skill_name'] . " is available in " . $row['city'];
            }
        }else{
            echo "No result found. Did you enter a city?";
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

A minor edit by ML: Corrected $row['skill'] to $row['skill_name']

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly. The Placeholders were an important part of the solution. There also seems to be some slight difference between a query by PDO and MYSQLI. Whereas I could join skill.skill_id with team.skill using the index (skill_id) in the mysqli query, I only got a result when I joined literally skill.skill_name to team.skill with PDO. P.S.That said, it might also be the version of MySQL as I updated WAMP this week and prior to that the query worked. I ran a raw query on the database using the old version in mysqli and it came back empty. Maybe a freak accident that it worked.